# proliferation of interfaces in ASP.NET projects

Tags: c#, asp.net

On several ASP.NET projects, I see a one-to-one correspondence of interfaces and implementation classes.  For example, there will be both an `Account` and `IAccount`, `AccountService` and `IAccountService`, etc.

Is this really necessary?  If there were multiple implementations of each interface, it would make sense.  But with a one-to-one correspondence and no polymorphism, it seems like unnecessary duplication (violation of DRY principle).

It almost reminds me of early Spring or EJB projects where interfaces were a necessary evil for dealing with frameworks and dynamic proxy creation.  But as the frameworks matured and improved, those interfaces started to disappear.

Any ideas where this convention came from for C# and ASP.NET?

Comment: Too broad - could be many things - dependency injection, unit testing, mocking, resolving circular project references, etc.

Comment: It's not mocking/unit testing, since there's only one implementation - no mock implementation.  Or, the mock implementation is being created dynamically at runtime through Moq, which doesn't require an interface as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not saying _you_ are using any of these - I'm just saying those are possible reasons for creating interfaces on business objects and services.  Or is could just be some wacky developer that decides that _every_ object needs an interface for no logical reason.  In any case there's not a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: Correction: Moq does not require interfaces, but because C# methods are non-virtual by default, the convention seems to be to create interfaces for things you're likely to mock rather than to make everything virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The DRY principle is still in place: implementation is not duplicated, interface is just a contract.
The other implementation will come as soon as you start writing unit tests, i.e. mocks.

Comment: you still are duplicating all your properties, method signatures, etc. and have to touch two places instead of one to make a change.

Comment: In writing - yes, in the final goal, having at least testable code - no. BTW, Moq allows to mock only virtual methods. The rule of thumb I use is that every class, having methods, might be a good candidate for having an interface as a base type. Simple data object with getters/setters in most cases not need an interface.